# Old style in app purchase dialogue

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am testing in app purchases now. In my app I use auto-renew subscription with sandbox account. I use XCode 9.2, the device is iOS 11.2.6, swift v4. Everything is working as expected, but I always get this dialogue then I press the "subscribe" button:

[image]

I saw the video from WWDC. Here is the screenshot from WWDC 2017 - Session 305 - Advanced StoreKit.

[image]

I am not sure, maybe this is normal behaviour. Maybe this is because of my sandbox account. Is it possible to get this new dialogue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, this is completely normal!

For some reason purchases inside of a sandbox (such as using a sandbox account or on TestFlight) will still use the old UI.

It's not clear *why* Apple has made this decision, or perhaps they simply never bothered to change it.

Either way, it's nothing to worry about on your part :)

Comment: @Alex I will get Advanced  storekit dialog in live app right?